# Как строку преобразовать в имя пэкеджа

Tags: java, java-8

```
new wolParser().Tokens.putAll(com.snaulx.wolparser.platforms.(buffer.toString()).Parser.addTokens());
```

buffer - это StringBuilder полученный из ввода пользователя.
(buffer.toString()) это название пэкеджа и мне надо преобразовать его так, чтобы в Map Tokens добавился Map из пэкеджа введённого пользователем. Как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону java Reflection API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-то интересно решение этой проблемы, то я скинул работающий код внизу.

```
Parser parser = (Parser) Class.forName("com.snaulx.wolparser.platforms." + buffer.toString() + ".Parser").newInstance();
new wolParser().Tokens.putAll(parser.addTokens());
```